# In C#, how do I compare the datemodified property of a local file with an Amazon S3 file?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I've got some local files that need to be updated from S3 occasionally. I'd prefer to update them only if the S3 version is newer. I can't quite understand how to use the

```
    ModifiedSinceDate
```

property in S3 Objects. In fact, I'm not sure whether to use Metadata, or if there is something else I'm supposed to be checking.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
 GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(my_bucketName).WithKey(s3filepath);

                using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                {

                    string s3DateModified = response.ModifiedSinceDate;  // Complete psuedo code
                    DateTime s3_creationTime = DateTime.Convert(s3DateModified);  //Complete psuedo code
                    DateTime local_creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\file.txt");

                    if (s3_creationTime > local_CreationTime)
                    {
                        //download the S3 object;
                    }
                }
```

Thanks so much!

EDIT---------------------------------------

I think I'm almost there... I'm writing the date modified as a meta-tag when I originally upload the object:

```
PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
                        .WithFilePath(savePath)
                        .WithBucketName(bucketName)
                        .WithKey(tempFileName)
                        .WithMetaData("Last-Modified", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Then using this for the check/download:

```
 using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                {
                    string lastModified = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-last-modified"];
                    DateTime s3LastModified = Convert.ToDateTime(lastModified);
                    string dest = Path.Combine(@"c:\Temp\", localFileName);
                    DateTime localLastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(dest);
                    if (!File.Exists(dest))
                    {
                        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
                    }
                    if (s3LastModified > localLastModified)
                    {
                        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
                    }

                }
```

Something's breaking, I think perhaps the WriteResponseStream is asynchronous, and it's trying two respnse.WriteResponseStreamtToFile(dest) at the same time. Anyways, I'll update this if I can get it nailed down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`GetObjectMetadata`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetObjectMetadata.htm) to retrieve information about an object without actually downloading the object itself.

The [`GetObjectMetadataResponse`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_GetObjectMetadataResponse.htm) class has a `LastModified` property or you could use custom Metadata I guess.

Then you would use `GetObject` to actually download and save the file.

Something like:

```
using (GetObjectMetadataResponse response = client.GetObjectMetadata(request))
{
    DateTime s3LastModified = response.LastModified;
    string dest = Path.Combine(@"c:\Temp\", localFileName);
    DateTime localLastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(dest);
    if (!File.Exists(dest) || s3LastModified > localLastModified)
    {
        // Use GetObject to download and save file
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Geoff- Thanks so much for your help. This basically works, but the response.LastModified results can be strange. I'm not sure if it's because the object is being cached, but the DateTime returned from S3 can be different with each call. Have you ever had that problem? Otherwise, this would work perfectly.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master - That's strange. I've not noticed that before although I haven't used the `LastModified` property much. Are they random dates or always a more recent date as though the file has been uploaded again?

Comment: I couldn't discern a pattern, to be honest with you. I'm trying to understand if putting the same exact file on S3 twice, would yield the same LastModified result, or would they be different. In other words, is copying a file to S3 considered Modifying it?

Comment: @Hairgami_Master - yes copying/overwriting a file would definitely change the `LastModified` date.

Comment: Thanks Geoff- Your help is much appreciated!